# Primitive function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question.
Does the function $z/(z^2+1)$ have primitive function in 
a) $ \mathbb{C} \backslash \{-i,i\}$ 
b) $ \mathbb{C} \backslash [-i,i]$

I tried with Cauchy theorem but I did not do it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also an open interval is denoted with parentheses, not braces.

Comment: @RossMillikan, I think the OP means the two-point *set* $ \{-i,i\}$.

Comment: @lhf:  probably so,  thanks

Comment: It means without point $-i$ and without point $i$ in point a)

Comment: Hint: Use residues to calculate the contour integral along a big circle that goes around both poles.